# SomeClass.class

Tags: java

Подскажите пожалуйста для чего это?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.class` взятый из имени класса означает, что вы берете объект [`java.lang.Class`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html), который представляет из себя информацию о вашем классе. Такой же объект можно получить, если из экземпляра класса взять `getClass()`

```
Print myPrint = new Print();
System.out.println(Print.class.getName());
System.out.println(myPrint.getClass().getName());
```